# Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type

Tags: java, spring, microservices

We are implementing microservice architecture.

I have deployed eureka server in external tomcat server i.e tomcat9 as context path "barpp-serviceregistry"

When i am connecting from the client, we are getting the following error

```
2022-12-22 08:18:55.863  INFO 1460 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:9090/barapp-serviceregistry/}, exception=Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8] stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:778)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:145)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:135)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1101)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1014)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1531)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1498)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

the same code we run as standalone application, it works fine. Is there any configuration required while deploying to external tomcat, what am I missing here?

the following are the properties configuration

## Eureka server

```
spring:
  application:
    name: barapp-serviceregistry
#server:
#  port: ${port:8761}
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9090/barpp-serviceregistry/
```

## Eureka client

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9090/barapp-serviceregistry/
```

Please help on it

checked with different blogs and tried with different options like adding the headers

Comment: Have a look at the HTML you are getting.

Comment: we are not getting any html.. but the content type we are getting as text/html. the same we can see in error

Comment: So the contents of the response is what you expect, but the header is wrong?